# Why does maven install give this error with npm?

Tags: java, angular, maven

I did a merge of two branches and just after that I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-npm
>   (install node and npm) on project frontend: Could not extract the npm
>   archive: Could not extract archive:
>   'C:\Users\User.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett\npm\5.6.0\npm-5.6.0.tar.gz':
>   EOFException -> [Help 1]

I looked on google and stackoverflow but didn't find anything that fixes it.

What should I try?

(Spring back-end with Angular front-end)

Comment: consider post your pom.xml

Comment: I strongly recommend to turn on checksum policy See for details https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just delete this folder from your local repository, and run your build again:

```
**delete => C:\Users\User.m2\repository\com\github\eirslett**
```

It seems that `npm tar.gz` was corrupted during the download.

Comment: Still I'm facing this issue